# Intermittent Kernel Panic, Trap at 0x00c5e290

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, kernel-panic

Do you guys have any idea as to what might be causing the following kernel panic?

I've already repaired file permissions and would like to avoid reinstalling os x.

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  586598 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          1
Anonymous UUID:                    BC9FA9D9-10CC-48A5-B4D4-51EE5A71DA29

Tue Sep 10 21:55:13 2013
panic(cpu 0 caller 0x2abf6a): Kernel trap at 0x00c5e290, type 14=page fault,
registers:
CR0: 0x8001003b, CR2: 0x000000a8, CR3: 0x00100000, CR4: 0x00000660
EAX: 0x00000000, EBX: 0x8260e2d0, ECX: 0x0c673800, EDX: 0x00000000
CR2: 0x000000a8, EBP: 0x52d4a908, ESI: 0x00000009, EDI: 0x0c673800
EFL: 0x00010246, EIP: 0x00c5e290, CS:  0x00000008, DS:  0x00000010
Error code: 0x00000000

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address (4 potential args on stack)
0x52d4a6e8 : 0x21b837 (0x5dd7fc 0x52d4a71c 0x223ce1 0x0)
0x52d4a738 : 0x2abf6a (0x59e3d0 0xc5e290 0xe 0x59e59a)
0x52d4a818 : 0x2a1a78 (0x52d4a830 0x0 0x52d4a908 0xc5e290)
0x52d4a828 : 0xc5e290 (0xe 0x48 0x10 0x10)
0x52d4a908 : 0xcd776b (0x44329000 0x4456a000 0x445dc000 0xb688f00)
0x52d4a958 : 0xcd7314 (0x4456a000 0x44344d20 0x0 0x81)
0x52d4a978 : 0xc6bc46 (0x4456a000 0xb984000 0x0 0x0)
0x52d4aab8 : 0xca55d8 (0x4456a000 0x1 0x52d4abcc 0x52d4abc8)
0x52d4ab68 : 0xc67fe1 (0x4456a000 0x1 0x52d4abcc 0x52d4abc8)
0x52d4abe8 : 0x56da06 (0x4456a000 0x0 0x52d4ae3c 0x52d4ac74)
0x52d4ac38 : 0x56e2a5 (0xcf6720 0x4456a000 0xd4aa388 0x1)
0x52d4ac88 : 0x56eb59 (0x4456a000 0x10 0x52d4acd0 0x0)
0x52d4ada8 : 0x286638 (0x4456a000 0x10 0xd4aa388 0x1)
0x52d4be58 : 0x21dbe5 (0xd4aa360 0x89ae5a0 0x1fa538 0xf937)
0x52d4be98 : 0x210a86 (0xd4aa300 0x0 0xbddff80 0xb78d3f0)
0x52d4bef8 : 0x216f84 (0xd4aa300 0x0 0x0 0x0)
0x52d4bf78 : 0x295c57 (0x91ed828 0x0 0x0 0x0)
0x52d4bfc8 : 0x2a256d (0x91ed824 0x1 0x10 0x91ed824)
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace (with dependencies):
         com.apple.GeForce(6.3.6)@0xc5c000->0xd12fff
            dependency: com.apple.NVDAResman(6.3.6)@0x96e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.2.1)@0x961000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.6.5)@0x928000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.2.1)@0x93f000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: firefox

Mac OS version:
10K549

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011;
root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386
System model name: MacBookPro5,1 (Mac-F42D86C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 36303727739057
unloaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AirPortBrcm43xx    423.91.27 (addr 0xeeb000, size
0x1900544) - last unloaded 91799879686
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor    1.9.3d0 - last loaded 25718487475
com.apple.driver.AGPM    100.12.31
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver    2.0.5f14
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA    2.0.5f14
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC    1.57
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC    1.5.1
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.1d2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver    1.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPenrynProfile    17
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.7
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl    1.0.20
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    4.7.0a1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl    2.10.6
com.apple.GeForce    6.3.6
com.apple.kext.AppleSMCLMU    1.5.2d10
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons    201.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard    201.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController    303.8
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient    2.6.8
com.apple.BootCache    31.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager    160.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage    1.6.4
com.apple.driver.AirPortBrcm43224    428.42.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    4.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort    2.1.7
com.apple.nvenet    2.0.17
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI    4.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBOHCI    4.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM    1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC    1.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET    1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons    1.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC    1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient    142.6.0
com.apple.security.sandbox    1
com.apple.security.quarantine    0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall    2.1.14
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement    142.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController    1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileReadCounterAction    17
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI    1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib    2.0.5f14
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileTimestampAction    10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileThreadInfoAction    14
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileRegisterStateAction    10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileKEventAction    10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileCallstackAction    20
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface    74.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    2.4.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily    10.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily    1.8.3fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController    2.0.5f14
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily    2.0.5f14
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily    4.7.0a1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC    3.1.0d5
com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal    6.3.6
com.apple.NVDAResman    6.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport    2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily    41
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController    2.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController    2.4.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily    2.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch    207.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver    4.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub    4.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite    3.9.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice    2.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily    1.6
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily    1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily    1.6.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter    402.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI    1.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily    2.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family    320.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient    4.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily    1.10
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily    4.2.4
com.apple.driver.NVSMU    2.2.7
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily    1.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily    1.1
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch    1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet    6
com.apple.driver.DiskImages    289.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily    1.6.3
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform    1.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.3.0
Model: MacBookPro5,1, BootROM MBP51.007E.B06, 2 processors, Intel Core 2
Duo, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.33f8
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT, NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT, PCIe, 256 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: global_name
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D),
Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.10.131.42.4)
Bluetooth: Version 2.4.5f3, 2 service, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS543225L9SA02, 232.89 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-868
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x06100000 / 2
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8213,
0x06110000 / 4
USB Device: Built-in iSight, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8507, 0x24400000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.),
0x0236, 0x04600000 / 3
USB Device: IR Receiver, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8242, 0x04500000 / 2
```

Comment: Why are you worried about having to reinstall *Windows*? Does it only happen in Firefox? Could it be caused by a bad/outdated plugin?

Comment: ...have to correct myself, i just checked the version on my affected IMac and its Version 30 not 26, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is crashing in the video kext (com.apple.GeForce). It is probably a bug in Firefox or a FireFox extension. You could try switching browsers, or disable all of your FireFox extensions and see if it goes away. If it does, slowly re-enable the extensions (1 per day at the fastest) to see when it starts happening again.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with older Macs and Firefox 26 and going back to Version 25 seems to help.

> Reverting back to Firefox 25 has resolved the issue on the iMac.

<sup>Source: https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/984953</sup>